# In C, working in Linux, when will accessing arrays out of bounds cause a seg fault?

Tags: linux, operating-system

If I access an array out of bounds in Linux, (and Windows, and probably everything, but I feel I should be clear), I can sometimes access the memory there and sometimes it just immediately segfaults.  I'm wondering what is the condition for the segfault, and why doesn't it get triggered all the time?  Here is my guess, if someone can confirm or deny:

The memory is allocated to the process with page granularity, which would be 4KiB on the x86 (32 bit anyway, not sure about 64 bit).  Therefore, I should theoretically be able to access anything beyond my array as long as I stay within that current page and no exceptions will even be raised.

Next, if I *do* access beyond that 4KiB boundary, it's possible that I'm accessing memory that already belongs to the program and is nicely mapped to an actual physical memory location in my virtual address space.  Once again, no problems happen since that memory is mine in the first place (well, problems happen in that I'm accessing out of bounds, but no OS exceptions occur).

On the other hand, if my array access tries to access the restricted kernel portion of my process, I get a segfault exception even though it's memory that **is** mapped to physical memory.

Finally, if I'm trying to access memory that exists in the virtual address space but not the physical yet, I have two cases:

1) I'm *extremely* unlucky and I've just so happened to address a piece of memory for which a valid page exists in secondary storage, so the page fault exception just loads the new page and I can keep accessing out of bounds

2) Probably way more likely, I try to access a piece of memory in the virtual address space for which there is no valid page, so NOW the MMU throws the seg fault.

Is any of that right?  Are there more conditions?

Comment: Trying to reason why something bad doesn't happen when your program has undefined behavior is kind of pointless. Fix the instances of UB and rest easy knowing that your program won't need some lucky fluke to keep working.

Comment: The segfault can happen indirectly. If you write outside of the array bounds, that may cause another function or process to use invalid data, which itself causes a segfault, not your original action.

Comment: @StoryTeller: it's not pointless.  It helps me to better understand memory management and virtual memory.  I'm also working on writing my own OS, which means I will have to implement all of this anyway, hence why I ask.  Knowledge is valid even if there are ways to avoid the consequences

Comment: Then your question isn't about C. Because C doesn't define a segfault to happen for illegal memory access.

Comment: Agreed with @StoryTeller. This is not a C issue. And trying to define the behaviour of **undefined** behaviour is just a waste of time you better use to learn how to write correct programs.

Comment: Fair enough.  I guess the operating-system tag makes more sense then

Comment: @Olaf: unless you're writing the OS, at which point you have to **define** at least when the fault occurs

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky: Not really. There is no requirement for an OS to catch application errors. Most bare-metal embedded OS and classical PC OS like DOS or the old MAC OS don't. Even uC Linux could not detect such problem without MMU support in the CPU. And the fault occurs if the code invokes undefined behaviour; that's in turn not really a matter of the OS.

Comment: And that's sort of what I'm getting at with my question.  I could, for example, not enable paging at all and just give every process access to all of memoy.  This would be a bad idea in many OS's but that's how embedded systems work, for instance.  I am just generally interested in the processes is all.

Comment: It can *sometimes* be satisfying to explain the result of undefined behaviour: when in my above example you find a bug, to assure yourself that it really did result in a crash at an unrelated part of the program, and that there isn't another undiscovered bug lurking - although "there *is* always one more bug" (Lubarsky's Law of Cybernetic Entomology).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a whole sequence of events that takes place. The abomination that is the C programming language (and its derivatives) does not do range checking on arrays.

(For now assume you are doing an access outside the array bounds)

Because memory management is based on pages, anything access the memory in any way allowed by the array's actual memory as long as you do not go over a page boundary.

If you do go over a page boundary, the processor has to go to the page tables

1. There may not be a page table entry for the page. => Access Violation
2. There may be a page table entry for the page and it is not mapped. => Access Violation
3. The page may be restricted to a higher access mode (e.g. Kernel, Supervisor, Executive). If so => Access violation.
4. You may attempt to access the page in a manner not permitted (e.g write to a read only page). If so => Access violation

If the logical page you attempt to access has a mapping and you attempt to access it in a manner allowed, you can hang yourself in C that way.

Answer (score 1):

You covered most of it. The only other things I can think of are related to general protection faults ex: you went over your page boundary and even though that page is valid and mapped, it isn't marked as readable/writable, the page contains code not data, etc...